# how to change color of activity indicator in iOS

Tags: ios, colors, uiactivityindicatorview, uicolor

I want to change the color of the activity Indicator in iOS.
However, I do not want to create a custom indicator. There is a color property for the activity Indicator but it's not showing up in xcode.
Please advice.

Comment: This is a solution that I found: 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22670582/2578240

Answer (score 10):

[From the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006830-CH3-SW12):

> **color**
>   The color of the activity indicator.
>
> If you set a color for an activity indicator, it overrides the color
>   provided by the activityIndicatorViewStyle property.

Notice that it is **iOS 5.0 and later** only.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the default activity indicator's color.

Comment: You can... but you really shouldn't. The only way you can is to access a view down in UIActivityIndicators view heiarchy and Apple Will not let your app in if it does that. Id recommend creating your own view that does the same thing and you can make it look like whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

just fyi, another way to do progress view  http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD