# UIActivityViewController with custom UIActivity displays color image as gray

Tags: iphone, image, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I created a custom UIActivity to display in a share sheet.  I created an 60x60 icon (png file) in full color, but when it's displayed it only shows the outline in gray.  I don't see what I've written incorrectly.  I hope someone sees what I've missed.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Here is my code...

```
@implementation MyActivity

#pragma mark - Overrides
- (NSString *)activityType {
    return @"MyType";
}

- (NSString *)activityTitle {
    return @"ShareMe";
}

- (UIImage *)activityImage {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyIcon_60x60.png"];
}

- (BOOL)canPerformWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems {
    return YES;
}

- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems {
    // Do Something
}

+ (UIActivityCategory)activityCategory {
    return UIActivityCategoryShare;
}

@end
```

Comment: have you found any solution i am also facing the same issue? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The answer below is the only thing I've found.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try adding an **underscore** to the method in the subclassed UIActivity class

```
- (UIImage *)_activityImage {}
```

You lose the rounded grey bounding box though

Comment: Yeah, this totally works - have you tried to get it through Apples approval process though? It's a private API but maybe you can sneak it through...

Comment: Hi,  really thank you so much its working fine for me, But i don't  how its working, Just changing underscore( _ ).

Comment: @BrandonA override activityImage method of UIActivity to display images.As per apple Action image should be grayscale image if its colored it will displayed as grayscla image.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure it's a bug or feature, but in iOS 8 if activityCategory is **UIActivityCategoryShare** it shows a nice rounded color icon. It shows a grey box in iOS 7. 
_activityImage looks a private API for me.

```
+ (UIActivityCategory)activityCategory {
    return UIActivityCategoryShare;
}
```

Comment: here's a more detailed sol. about activityCategory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19469248/1707547

Comment: This is the correct solution, the _activityImage maybe can cause a rejection from apple?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that is the way it is supposed to work. The [Apple Docs state](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActivity/activityImage):

> The alpha channel of the image is used as a mask to generate the final
>   image that is presented to the user. Any color data in the image
>   itself is ignored...

If you want to use a full color image you will have to replicate the behavior of the `UIActivityViewController` and add support for color images.

I recommend you look at [Overshare](https://github.com/overshare/overshare-kit) as it supports full-color icons.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I read through that paragraph and that sentence didn't register.  It's a shame about the color.  Unless I spend a lot of time reinventing the wheel, I will not be able to display a color icon like YouTube's red icon.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10, set the `activityCategory` class property of your UIActivity subclass to .share.  This will cause the activity icon to appear in color in the top row of the UIActivityViewController.

In your UIActivity subclass:

```
class GroupMessageActivity: UIActivity
{
    ...

    override open class var activityCategory: UIActivityCategory
    {
        get
        {
            return UIActivityCategory.share;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The default value or `UIActivityCategory.action` uses the alpha channel to produce a grayscale image in the bottom "action" row.