# Is there a standard iOS UI control which implements open-in like UI?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I want to build open-in like UI (see picture below).

It should include a list of icons representing actions and cancel button. I want pretty much `UIAlertController` only with icons (vs plain text).

Is there a standard iOS control which does something like or that or will I have to build/find a custom UI control for that?

[image]

Comment: @AlejandroIván I believe it's deprecated in iOS 8

Comment: In Apple's docs I see `UIActivity`, `UIActivityViewController` (this ^) and `UIActionSheet`. Yes, `UIActionSheet` was deprecated in iOS8. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html  Also see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891730/uiactivityviewcontroller-with-custom-uiactivity-displays-color-image-as-gray

Comment: @mc01 Yeah. It looks so. Do you want to extract it as the answer, so people can upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's docs, each displayed service/action is a [UIActivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html), which is an abstract class, displayed in a [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivityViewController) which you can customize. There are several built-in services, and you can create your own w/custom icons. Yes, UIActionSheet was deprecated in iOS8.

> The UIActivityViewController class is a standard view controller that
>   you can use to offer various services from your application. The
>   system provides several standard services, such as copying items to
>   the pasteboard, posting content to social media sites, sending items
>   via email or SMS, and more. Apps can also define custom services.
>
> Your app is responsible for configuring, presenting, and dismissing
>   this view controller. Configuration for the view controller involves
>   specifying the data objects on which the view controller should act.
>   (You can also specify the list of custom services your app supports.)
>   When presenting the view controller, you must do so using the
>   appropriate means for the current device. On iPad, you must present
>   the view controller in a popover. On iPhone and iPod touch, you must
>   present it modally.

Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891730/uiactivityviewcontroller-with-custom-uiactivity-displays-color-image-as-gray) on some image gotchas ...
And [this tutorial](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2015/07/uiactivityviewcontroller-part-2.html) on adding a custom `UIActivity` to the view.